# Pydantic inherit generic class

Tags: python, generics, pydantic

New to python and pydantic, I come from a typescript background. I was wondering if you can inherit a generic class?

In typescript the code would be as follows

```
interface GenericInterface<T> {
  value: T
}

interface ExtendsGeneric<T> extends GenericInterface<T> {
  // inherit value from GenericInterface
  otherValue: string
}

const thing: ExtendsGeneric<Number> = {
  value: 1,
  otherValue: 'string'
}
```

What I have been trying is something along the lines of

```
#python3.9
from pydantic.generics import GenericModel
from typing import TypeVar
from typing import Generic

T = TypeVar("T", int, str)

class GenericField(GenericModel, Generic[T]):
    value: T

class ExtendsGenericField(GenericField[T]):
    otherValue: str

ExtendsGenericField[int](value=1, otherValue="other value")
```

And I get the error of `TypeError: Too many parameters for ExtendsGenericField; actual 1, expected 0`.
This sort of checks out because in the [Pydantic docs](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/models/#generic-models) it explicitly states "In order to declare a generic model...Use the TypeVar instances as annotations where you will want to replace them..." The easy workaround is to make `ExtendsGeneric` inherit from `GenericModel` and have `value` in its own class definition, but I was trying to reuse classes.

Is inheriting a value from a generic class possible?

Comment: You need to give one agrument as python dictionary ExtendsGenericField[int]({value:1, otherValue:"other value"})

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Generics are a little weird in Python, and the problem is that `ExtendsGenericField` itself isn't declared as generic. To solve, just add `Generic[T]` as a super class of `ExtendsGenericField`:

```py
from pydantic.generics import GenericModel
from typing import TypeVar
from typing import Generic

T = TypeVar("T", int, str)

class GenericField(GenericModel, Generic[T]):
    value: T

class ExtendsGenericField(GenericField[T], Generic[T]):
    otherValue: str

ExtendsGenericField[int](value=1, otherValue="other value")
```

Comment: Quick fix! I figured I was missing something silly like that. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Not sure but referring yours my code worked :)

```
from datetime import datetime
from pydantic import BaseModel, parse_obj_as
from enum import Enum
import json
from typing import TypeVar, Generic
from pydantic.generics import GenericModel

class TradeOverlapping(BaseModel):
    COBDate: str
    DBServer: str

class EventType(Enum):
    STH_READY= 'STH_READY'

T = TypeVar("T")
class KafkaEvent(GenericModel,Generic[T]):
    Source: str
    Version: str
    TimeStamp: datetime
    Event: EventType
    Data: T

p = KafkaEvent[TradeOverlapping].parse_obj({"Source":"TOPIC","Version":"1.0","TimeStamp":"2022-08-03 06:49:17","Event":EventType('STH_READY'),"Data":TradeOverlapping(COBDate="2023-04-05", DBServer="DB_SERVER")})
print("Producer:")
print(p.json())

print("----------------------------")

value = '{"Source":"TOPIC","Version":"1.0","TimeStamp":"2022-08-03 06:49:17","Event":"STH_READY","Data":{"COBDate":"2023-04-05","DBServer":"DB_SERVER"}}'
obj = parse_obj_as(KafkaEvent[TradeOverlapping], json.loads(value))
print("Consumer:")
print(obj)
```

Comment: Output:

Producer:
{"Source": "TOPIC", "Version": "1.0", "TimeStamp": "2022-08-03T06:49:17", "Event": "STH_READY", "Data": {"COBDate": "2023-04-05", "DBServer": "DB_SERVER"}}
----------------------------
Consumer:
Source='TOPIC' Version='1.0' TimeStamp=datetime.datetime(2022, 8, 3, 6, 49, 17) Event=<EventType.STH_READY: 'STH_READY'> Data=TradeOverlapping(COBDate='2023-04-05', DBServer='DB_SERVER')

Answer (score 0):

Since Pydantic v2 (at least with v2.6.x), the following works ([reference](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/concepts/models/#generic-models)):

```py
# at least with Python 3.9
from typing import Generic, TypeVar
from pydantic import BaseModel

T = TypeVar("T")

class BaseClass(BaseModel, Generic[T]):
    value: T

class ChildClass(BaseClass[T], Generic[T]):
    other_value: str


x = ChildClass[int](value=1, other_value="other value")

type(x)
# __main__.ChildClass[int]
```